# Javascript: Convert a hexadecimal encoded String to a hexadecimal byte

Tags: javascript, node.js

Now I have to convert the hexadecimal encoded in a String to a byte hexadecimal.

```
var str = "5e" 

var b = // Should be 0x5e then.

if str = "6b", then b = 0x6b and so on.
```

Is there any function in javascript, like in java

`Byte.parseByte(str, 16)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `b = parseInt('5e', 16)`

Comment: You can use Int8Array (signed) or Uint8Array (unsigned) types with the native function parseInt(hexString, 16)

Comment: What is a "hexadecimal byte"?

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is `parseInt`

```
parseInt("6b", 16) // returns 107
```

The first argument to `parseInt` is a string representation of the number and the second argument is the base. Use 10 for decimal and 16 for hexadecimal.

Comment: No, it gives the value 107

Comment: 0x6b is just another way to write 107

Comment: Use Int8Array or Uint8Array to store as byte.

Comment: The problem is that I expect an output of 0x6b which can be used to pass as a buffer.

Comment: I don't understand. In Javascript (and most other programming languages), 0x6b is just another way to write 107. They are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, if you expect "an output of 0x6b" from the string "6b" then just prepend "0x" to your string, and further manipulate as you need. There is no Javascript type that will output a hexadecimal in a readable format that you'll see prefixed with '0x' other than a string.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using just

```
new Buffer("32476832", 'hex')
```

this solved my problem and gave me the desired buffer

```
<Buffer 32 47 68 32>
```